# Kernel Compilation & missing modules error after `make install`

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtualization, rhel, vmware-workstation

I am compiling kernel 2.6.32-220.el6 downloaded from redhat's ftp server on RHEL 6.2 (VMWARE virtual machine). I have extracted kernel source from downloaded rpm and inside it, I have untared the actual .bz which contains source code and copied it to /usr/src/kernel. After that I have performed the following steps:

make menuconfig /*Here I disabled "module versioning support" and "module signature verification"*/

make clean

make

make modules

make modules_install

make install

Now every thing works fine until `make install`. At this point it gives me following error:

[root@localhost linux-2.6.32-220.23.1.el6 G2]# make install

> sh
>   /usr/src/kernels/kernel-2.6.32-220.23.1.el6.src/linux-2.6.32-220.23.1.el6/arch/x86/boot/install.sh
>   2.6.32 arch/x86/boot/bzImage \        System.map "/boot"
>
> ERROR: modinfo: could not find module vmhgfs
>
> ERROR: modinfo: could not find module vsock
>
> ERROR: modinfo: could not find module vmci

I searched these modules and all three modules are present in /lib/modules/2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64/misc/.

I dont know how to solve this issue. This seems like virtual machine issue as I am doing this on VM.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following:

1. First backup your VM.
2. Uninstall the VMware tools.
3. Try your steps above again.
4. Re-install VMware tools.